# dynamically create a grand total row in pandas/pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I currently have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| location | count | qty | approved_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phoenix | 24 | 300 | 15 |
| Dallas | 18 | 403 | 14 |

I would like to append a row to the dataframe that iterates over the columns and sums them, and then appends a new row to the bottom, including the value "Grand Total" in the 'location' column.  The resulting dataset should look like this:

| location | count | qty | approved_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phoenix | 24 | 300 | 15 |
| Dallas | 18 | 403 | 14 |
| Grand Total | 42 | 703 | 29 |

I am currently able to get this result this way:

```
    df = df.append({'location' : 'Grand Total', 'count' : 
    df['count'].sum(), 'qty' : df['qty'].sum(),
    'approved_count' : df['approved_count'].sum()}, ignore_index = True)
```

however I would like to be able to dynamically iterate over the columns and sum, excluding the 'location' column from the sum process.  Is this possible with Pandas or Pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.set_index("location")
df.loc["Grand Total"] = df.sum()
df = df.reset_index()

>>> df
      location  count  qty  approved_count
0      Phoenix     24  300              15
1       Dallas     18  403              14
2  Grand Total     42  703              29
```

Or in one line using `concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df.set_index("location"), df.drop("location",axis=1).sum().rename("Grand Total").to_frame().T]).reset_index()
         index  count  qty  approved_count
0      Phoenix     24  300              15
1       Dallas     18  403              14
2  Grand Total     42  703              29
```

Comment: I like this, however is there a way to then display the Index column as a regular column? I'd like it to be included as a regular column, as the web IDE I am running does not display the indexes.

Comment: Just `reset_index()`. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Using Pyspark as below -

**Input Data**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Phoenix', 24, 300, 15), ('Dallas', 18, 403, 14)], schema = ["location", "count", "qty", "approved_count"])
df.show()

+--------+-----+---+--------------+
|location|count|qty|approved_count|
+--------+-----+---+--------------+
| Phoenix|   24|300|            15|
|  Dallas|   18|403|            14|
+--------+-----+---+--------------+
```

Creating a new dataframe to find the summation of columns

```
df1 = df.withColumn("location", lit("Grand Total")).groupBy("location").agg(*[sum(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != "location"])
df1.show()

+-----------+-----+---+--------------+
|   location|count|qty|approved_count|
+-----------+-----+---+--------------+
|Grand Total|   42|703|            29|
+-----------+-----+---+--------------+
```

Union both the dataframes to append the rows

```
df.unionByName(df1).show()

+-----------+-----+---+--------------+
|   location|count|qty|approved_count|
+-----------+-----+---+--------------+
|    Phoenix|   24|300|            15|
|     Dallas|   18|403|            14|
|Grand Total|   42|703|            29|
+-----------+-----+---+--------------+
```